# Pydantic color type hex only

Tags: python, colors, fastapi, pydantic

I have the pydantic model that have color property

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.color import Color

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    color: Color
```

And I define FastAPI router that returns `MyModel`

```py
@router.get("/", response_model=MyModel)
async def get_my_model() -> MyModel:
    item = await DbItem.get()
    return MyModel(**item.dict())
```

In this setup pydantic converts colors to named colors (e.g. `black`).

My frontend don't recognize named colors.

How can I point pydantic to return hex colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Color.as_hex`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#color-type):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.color import Color


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    color: Color


my_model = MyModel(color=Color("black"))
print(my_model.color.as_hex())  # '#000'
```

To get the hex value in your response, you can add a custom [json encoder](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders):

```py
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    color: Color

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {Color: lambda c: c.as_hex()}
```

Comment: It's OK when I want to get color value "in place". But I want to get hex value in response model